# Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be independent $\mathrm{Exp}(λ)$-distributed random variables. Find the probability that $X_1 < X_2 < X_3$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to figure out how to do this using exchangeability, but can't figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\Pr[X_1<X_2<X_3] = \Pr[X_1<X_3<X_2] = \Pr[X_2<X_1<X_3] = \Pr[X_2<X_3<X_1] = \Pr[X_3<X_1<X_2] = \Pr[X_3<X_2<X_1].
$$
This idea will work for any non-atomic probability distribution (i.e. one such that $\Pr[X=x] = 0$ for all $x$).

Comment: I prefer "atomless" to "non-atomic" because "non-atomic" can be mistaken for "not-atomic", which is not the same thing.  "Not atomic" in this case would mean it is not a discrete distribution; "atomless" would mean it has no discrete part. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "non-atomic", could you elaborate on that?  From Wikipedia, all I can gather is that the probability would equal 0?

Comment: An *atom* $x$ for a random variable $X$ is a value whose probability is strictly positive, $\Pr[X=x] > 0$. A *non-atomic* or *atomless* measure has no atoms. In our case, what we actually need is that $\Pr[X_1=X_2] = 0$.

Comment: Ok I understand (more or less) the non-atomic, but when it comes to computing a probability, how is that helping me?  Is it because through exchangeability, the only way for the statement to be satisfied is if the probability is 0?

Comment: Perhaps you can start with computing the probability $\Pr[X_1 < X_2]$ using $\Pr[X_1 < X_2] = \Pr[X_2 < X_1]$ and $\Pr[X_1 = X_2] = 0$.